# iOS WKWebView Single Sign On (SSO) suppport

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, single-sign-on, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView control in my iOS app. I have Microsoft SharePoint wopiframe with Word Online document in WKWebView with "Sign in" button on it, by clicking on that I'm showing new WKWebView:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    // A nil targetFrame means a new window (from Apple doc)
    if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
        // Let create a new webview on the fly with the provided configuration,
        // set us as the UI delegate and return the handle to the parent webview
        let popup = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
        popup.uiDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(popup)
        return popup
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Also when WKWebView trying to close itself, I'm removing it:

```
func webViewDidClose(_ webView: WKWebView) {
    webView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The problem is after closing I still see the "Sign in" button in wopiframe, and page reload didn't help. In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/customize-webviews) I've found that WKWebView doesn't share cookies or web site data with other WKWebView instances and doesn't support Single Sign On (SSO). Article also saying:

> For SSO to work, tokens need to be shared between apps. This requires a token cache, or broker application, such as Microsoft Authenticator for iOS.

Microsoft Authenticator for iOS isn't option for me, but what about token cache? What is it at all? Why does my Word Online wopiframe doesn't working after sign in?